# largest number that leaves same remainder while dividing 5958, 5430 and 5814?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Largest number that leaves same remainder while dividing 5958, 5430 and 5814 ?

---

$$5958 \equiv 5430 \equiv 5814 \pmod x$$
 $$3\times 17\times 19 \equiv 5\times 181\equiv 3\times 331\pmod x$$
$$969 \equiv 905\equiv 993\pmod x$$

After a bit of playing with the calculator,
I think the answer is $48$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Sorry if the answer is too obvious, I am still trying to wrap my head modular arithmetic and not very successful yet.It would be great help if anybody would give me some hints on how to proceed ahead. Thanks. $\ddot \smile$

Comment: The first congruence corresponds to the title. What do you mean with the other two congruences? Are you solving three problems at once here?

Comment: I see you divided all the terms by 6.  That's .. not really okay.   12 = 22 mod 10 but 6 != 11 mod 10.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okay, first we set it up even though we have no idea where we are going.

$5958 \equiv n \mod x$

$5430 \equiv n \mod x$

$5814 \equiv n \mod x$.

Then we noodle a bit to make it smaller and more pallatable.

$5958 - 5814 = 144 \equiv 0 \mod x$

$5814 - 5430 = 384 \equiv 0 \mod x$

and

$5958 - 5430 = 528 \equiv 0 \mod x$

Well, now it's very clear that $x$ is a common divisor and all we have to do is find the $x = \gcd(144,384, 528)$

$x = \gcd(144 = 2^43^2, 384 = 2^7*3, 528 = 2^4*3*11) = 2^4*3 = 48$.

And we're done.

Comment: we could noodle a bit further to get 528 - 384 = 144 = 0 mod x and so on and accidentally stumble onto the Euclidean Algorithm completely inadvertently.

Comment: ... then we wonder briefly "well, what *was* the remainder anyway" and then decide "screw it, I don't care".

Comment: ... then we decide the heck with it and calculate that the remainder was $n=6$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubts through this answer and the comment below the question. :)

Comment: Can you recommend a good book on modular arithmetic with difficult exercises, if you know any? my course is kind of basic and i am getting trouble doing tricky problems. Thanks. :)

Comment: Don't really have any recomendations.  Any number theory book covers it.  Ivan Niven's book was the one I learned from but any will do.

Answer (score 7):

Since $5958 \equiv 5430 \mod{x}$, then $x | 5958 -5430 = 528$.  Likewise $x | 
5958 - 5814 = 144$ and $x | 5814 - 5430 = 384$.  So $x$ is a common divisor of
$528,$ $144,$ and $384$.  So you want $x=\gcd(528, 144, 384) = 48$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 3):

Let the number leaving the same remainder be $a$ and the remainder be $b$.

So, $\gcd(5958-a,5430-a,5814-a)=b$

Note that

$(1)$ $$\gcd(x,y,z)=\gcd{\gcd(x,y)\gcd(y,z)}$$
$(2)$ $$\gcd(x,y) \mid x-y$$

Comment: thanks for the hints, took me a while but got them at last $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score -1):

The only "small" solutions (below 10000000) seem to be ${1,2,3,4,6,8,12,16,24,48}$. 
Of course, you can add $lcm({5958, 5430, 5814}) = 1741612770 $ to a solution and get another, bigger one.

The set above was found by letting do the computer what a computer can do best: Computing stuff. Here is the Haskell Code I used:

`` [x |  x <- [1..870806385 + 49], 5958 `mod` x == 5430 `mod` x, 5430 `mod` x == 5814 `mod` x] ``

Comment: You can't  add $1741612770$ to any of these, as it would then leave $5958$ etc. as remainders.

Comment: there can't be any solutions greater than 5430 so no point in pointing out that these are only the small ones.  If n > 5430 then the remainder dividing into 5430 is 5430.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question or i did not frame it well, either way thanks for putting the effort.